# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, server

I'm working on a weather app for Angela Yu's code boot-camp on Udemy.  Everything works well until i get to the JSON.parse line. I can not find out why I'm getting an error.

```
const https = require("https");
const app = express();
const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid={API-KEY-OMITED}&units=imperial&zip=97078";
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 https.get(url, (response) => {
     console.log(response.statusCode);

     response.on("data", (data) => {
         const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
         console.log(weatherData);
     })
 })

 res.send('server is running!')

})

app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}!`);
})
```

This is what I get in the terminal.

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server is running on port 3000!
200
undefined:1
{"cod":"200","message":0,"cnt":40,"list":[{"dt":1640034000,"main":{"temp":40.91,"feels_like":40.91,"temp_min":40.73,"temp_max":40.91,"pressure":1015,"sea_level":1015,"grnd_level":1009,"humidity":92,"temp_kf":0.1},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":90},"wind":{"speed":2.46,"deg":64,"gust":6.2},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":5.98},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-20 21:00:00"},{"dt":1640044800,"main":{"temp":40.86,"feels_like":40.86,"temp_min":40.77,"temp_max":40.86,"pressure":1016,"sea_level":1016,"grnd_level":1010,"humidity":94,"temp_kf":0.05},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":93},"wind":{"speed":2.71,"deg":31,"gust":4.74},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":3.15},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 00:00:00"},{"dt":1640055600,"main":{"temp":41.09,"feels_like":41.09,"temp_min":41.09,"temp_max":41.18,"pressure":1018,"sea_level":1018,"grnd_level":1012,"humidity":95,"temp_kf":-0.05},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":97},"wind":{"speed":2.13,"deg":23,"gust":4.07},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":1.29},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 03:00:00"},{"dt":1640066400,"main":{"temp":41.72,"feels_like":41.72,"temp_min":41.72,"temp_max":41.72,"pressure":1020,"sea_level":1020,"grnd_level":1013,"humidity":94,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":2.55,"deg":51,"gust":2.51},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.87,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 06:00:00"},{"dt":1640077200,"main":{"temp":41.25,"feels_like":39.47,"temp_min":41.25,"temp_max":41.25,"pressure":1019,"sea_level":1019,"grnd_level":1012,"humidity":93,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":85},"wind":{"speed":3.29,"deg":23,"gust":4.05},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 09:00:00"},{"dt":1640088000,"main":{"temp":40.26,"feels_like":37.96,"temp_min":40.26,"temp_max":40.26,"pressure":1019,"sea_level":1019,"grnd_level":1012,"humidity":95,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":89},"wind":{"speed":3.65,"deg":21,"gust":5.14},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 12:00:00"},{"dt":1640098800,"main":{"temp":39.15,"feels_like":39.15,"temp_min":39.15,"temp_max":39.15,"pressure":1019,"sea_level":1019,"grnd_level":1012,"humidity":94,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":1.83,"deg":47,"gust":1.83},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 15:00:00"},{"dt":1640109600,"main":{"temp":41.58,"feels_like":41.58,"temp_min":41.58,"temp_max":41.58,"pressure":1019,"sea_level":1019,"grnd_level":1012,"humidity":87,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":1.68,"deg":66,"gust":2.66},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 18:00:00"},{"dt":1640120400,"main":{"temp":44.89,"feels_like":44.89,"temp_min":44.89,"temp_max":44.89,"pressure":1017,"sea_level":1017,"grnd_level":1010,"humidity":82,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":2.33,"deg":57,"gust":3.49},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-21 21:00:00"},{"dt":1640131200,"main":{"temp":43.52,"feels_like":43.52,"temp_min":43.52,"temp_max":43.52,"pressure":1016,"sea_level":1016,"grnd_level":1009,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":1.83,"deg":190,"gust":1.9},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 00:00:00"},{"dt":1640142000,"main":{"temp":40.98,"feels_like":40.98,"temp_min":40.98,"temp_max":40.98,"pressure":1014,"sea_level":1014,"grnd_level":1007,"humidity":95,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":97},"wind":{"speed":1.63,"deg":162,"gust":1.77},"visibility":10000,"pop":0,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 03:00:00"},{"dt":1640152800,"main":{"temp":42.48,"feels_like":40.23,"temp_min":42.48,"temp_max":42.48,"pressure":1014,"sea_level":1014,"grnd_level":1007,"humidity":98,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":99},"wind":{"speed":3.94,"deg":175,"gust":12.62},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.74,"rain":{"3h":0.97},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 06:00:00"},{"dt":1640163600,"main":{"temp":45.55,"feels_like":39.47,"temp_min":45.55,"temp_max":45.55,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":1005,"humidity":93,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":13.13,"deg":193,"gust":29.59},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":4},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 09:00:00"},{"dt":1640174400,"main":{"temp":45.1,"feels_like":39.79,"temp_min":45.1,"temp_max":45.1,"pressure":1012,"sea_level":1012,"grnd_level":1005,"humidity":91,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":10.49,"deg":196,"gust":26.4},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":1.57},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 12:00:00"},{"dt":1640185200,"main":{"temp":45.77,"feels_like":41.02,"temp_min":45.77,"temp_max":45.77,"pressure":1011,"sea_level":1011,"grnd_level":1004,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":9.4,"deg":193,"gust":27.07},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.59,"rain":{"3h":0.33},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 15:00:00"},{"dt":1640196000,"main":{"temp":46.09,"feels_like":39.97,"temp_min":46.09,"temp_max":46.09,"pressure":1010,"sea_level":1010,"grnd_level":1003,"humidity":92,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":13.76,"deg":186,"gust":25.66},"visibility":6452,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":2.72},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 18:00:00"},{"dt":1640206800,"main":{"temp":46.15,"feels_like":39.67,"temp_min":46.15,"temp_max":46.15,"pressure":1007,"sea_level":1007,"grnd_level":1000,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":15.19,"deg":187,"gust":28.77},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":6.36},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-22 21:00:00"},{"dt":1640217600,"main":{"temp":45.7,"feels_like":39.43,"temp_min":45.7,"temp_max":45.7,"pressure":1005,"sea_level":1005,"grnd_level":998,"humidity":90,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate 
rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":13.89,"deg":187,"gust":27.69},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":3.19},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 00:00:00"},{"dt":1640228400,"main":{"temp":45.64,"feels_like":39.24,"temp_min":45.64,"temp_max":45.64,"pressure":1002,"sea_level":1002,"grnd_level":995,"humidity":87,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":14.34,"deg":184,"gust":29.01},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.62,"rain":{"3h":0.21},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 03:00:00"},{"dt":1640239200,"main":{"temp":46.45,"feels_like":39.87,"temp_min":46.45,"temp_max":46.45,"pressure":999,"sea_level":999,"grnd_level":992,"humidity":84,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":15.93,"deg":179,"gust":38.97},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.74,"rain":{"3h":0.6},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 06:00:00"},{"dt":1640250000,"main":{"temp":41.74,"feels_like":35.65,"temp_min":41.74,"temp_max":41.74,"pressure":999,"sea_level":999,"grnd_level":993,"humidity":91,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":10.33,"deg":245,"gust":22.88},"visibility":5223,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":5.69},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 09:00:00"},{"dt":1640260800,"main":{"temp":39.78,"feels_like":34.34,"temp_min":39.78,"temp_max":39.78,"pressure":1000,"sea_level":1000,"grnd_level":993,"humidity":92,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":7.96,"deg":213,"gust":20.74},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":1.46},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 12:00:00"},{"dt":1640271600,"main":{"temp":39.96,"feels_like":34.29,"temp_min":39.96,"temp_max":39.96,"pressure":1000,"sea_level":1000,"grnd_level":993,"humidity":92,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":95},"wind":{"speed":8.5,"deg":195,"gust":17.92},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.68,"rain":{"3h":0.24},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 15:00:00"},{"dt":1640282400,"main":{"temp":39.81,"feels_like":33.21,"temp_min":39.81,"temp_max":39.81,"pressure":1001,"sea_level":1001,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":93,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":91},"wind":{"speed":10.47,"deg":218,"gust":19.17},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":0.96},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 18:00:00"},{"dt":1640293200,"main":{"temp":43.43,"feels_like":38.03,"temp_min":43.43,"temp_max":43.43,"pressure":1001,"sea_level":1001,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":78,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":99},"wind":{"speed":9.66,"deg":244,"gust":19.75},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":0.8},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-23 21:00:00"},{"dt":1640304000,"main":{"temp":41.31,"feels_like":35.13,"temp_min":41.31,"temp_max":41.31,"pressure":1001,"sea_level":1001,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":74,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":76},"wind":{"speed":10.33,"deg":243,"gust":23.51},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":0.66},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 00:00:00"},{"dt":1640314800,"main":{"temp":39,"feels_like":32.31,"temp_min":39,"temp_max":39,"pressure":1002,"sea_level":1002,"grnd_level":995,"humidity":85,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":76},"wind":{"speed":10.22,"deg":218,"gust":22.88},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.58,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 03:00:00"},{"dt":1640325600,"main":{"temp":38.26,"feels_like":31.3,"temp_min":38.26,"temp_max":38.26,"pressure":1001,"sea_level":1001,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":96,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":88},"wind":{"speed":10.42,"deg":200,"gust":22.82},"visibility":899,"pop":0.83,"rain":{"3h":0.57},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 06:00:00"},{"dt":1640336400,"main":{"temp":38.89,"feels_like":31.21,"temp_min":38.89,"temp_max":38.89,"pressure":999,"sea_level":999,"grnd_level":992,"humidity":97,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":12.66,"deg":190,"gust":26.53},"visibility":72,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":2.06},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 09:00:00"},{"dt":1640347200,"main":{"temp":38.59,"feels_like":29.48,"temp_min":38.59,"temp_max":38.59,"pressure":995,"sea_level":995,"grnd_level":988,"humidity":96,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":16.8,"deg":177,"gust":35.63},"visibility":155,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":2.33},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 12:00:00"},{"dt":1640358000,"main":{"temp":36.75,"feels_like":30.02,"temp_min":36.75,"temp_max":36.75,"pressure":996,"sea_level":996,"grnd_level":989,"humidity":97,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10n"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":9.17,"deg":197,"gust":19.89},"visibility":293,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":3.56},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 15:00:00"},{"dt":1640368800,"main":{"temp":39.24,"feels_like":32.86,"temp_min":39.24,"temp_max":39.24,"pressure":997,"sea_level":997,"grnd_level":990,"humidity":92,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":9.64,"deg":184,"gust":22.73},"visibility":7697,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":1.02},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 18:00:00"},{"dt":1640379600,"main":{"temp":40.75,"feels_like":33.19,"temp_min":40.75,"temp_max":40.75,"pressure":995,"sea_level":995,"grnd_level":988,"humidity":91,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":100},"wind":{"speed":13.76,"deg":191,"gust":30.6},"visibility":7140,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":1.13},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-24 21:00:00"},{"dt":1640390400,"main":{"temp":40.42,"feels_like":33.6,"temp_min":40.42,"temp_max":40.42,"pressure":998,"sea_level":998,"grnd_level":991,"humidity":79,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":{"all":96},"wind":{"speed":11.41,"deg":252,"gust":27.09},"visibility":10000,"pop":1,"rain":{"3h":2.4},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-25 00:00:00"},{"dt":1640401200,"main":{"temp":37.81,"feels_like":32.34,"temp_min":37.81,"temp_max":37.81,"pressure":1001,"sea_level":1001,"grnd_level":994,"humidity":89,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":98},"wind":{"speed":7.27,"deg":204,"gust":18.72},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.54,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-25 03:00:00"},{"dt":1640412000,"main":{"temp":36.86,"feels_like":30.6,"temp_min":36.86,"temp_max":36.86,"pressure":1002,"sea_level":1002,"grnd_level":995,"humidity":93,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":98},"wind":{"speed":8.3,"deg":195,"gust":17.76},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.5,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-25 06:00:00"},{"dt":1640422800,"main":{"temp":36,"feels_like":29.88,"temp_min":36,"temp_max":36,"pressure":1003,"sea_level":1003,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":96,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":96},"wind":{"speed":7.72,"deg":203,"gust":16.89},"visibility":387,"pop":0.46,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-25 09:00:00"},{"dt":1640433600,"main":{"temp":36.7,"feels_like":31.66,"temp_min":36.7,"temp_max":36.7,"pressure":1003,"sea_level":1003,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":92,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13n"}],"clouds":{"all":97},"wind":{"speed":6.24,"deg":205,"gust":13.78},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.5,"snow":{"3h":0.17},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-25 12:00:00"},{"dt":1640444400,"main":{"temp":35.83,"feels_like":29.93,"temp_min":35.83,"temp_max":35.83,"pressure":1003,"sea_level":1003,"grnd_level":996,"humidity":91,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":72},"wind":{"speed":7.29,"deg":200,"gust":17.78},"visibility":10000,"pop":0.53,"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2021-12-25 15:00:00"},{"dt":1640455200,"main":{"temp":36.86,"feels_like":30.34,"temp_min":36.86,"temp_max":36.86,"pressure":1005,"sea_level":1005,"grnd_level":998,"humidity":96,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":{"all":86},"wind":{"speed":8.77,"deg":206,"gust":19.28

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pc\documents\webdev\theCompleteWebDevBootcamp-AngelaYu\apis\weatherproject\app.js:13:38)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:527:10)
    at flow (node:internal/streams/readable:1012:34)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:993:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Yep, error makes sense. You're trying to parse just a small piece of the overall response.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` event fires *every time* you get a *chunk* of data.

It doesn't fire once when you have **all** the data.

You're trying to parse a **piece** of JSON instead of the whole JSON text.

Look at [this example in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpgeturl-options-callback):

> ```
>   res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
>   res.on('end', () => {
>     try {
>       const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
>       console.log(parsedData);
>     } catch (e) {
>       console.error(e.message);
>     }
>   });
> ```

Each time you get a `data` event, add it to the data you already have. When you get an `end` event, then try to parse it.

---

Directly using the `http` and `https` modules is a pain. They aren't very friendly. I recommend using a wrapper with a friendlier API such as [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) (both of which return a promise that resolves when all the data is available).